# How to assign to variable true in pipe?

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, pipe

If id is null I want variable x to be true. I would use if and else but can't do that in pipe. Please help me.

```
  private x = false;
  private y = false;

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribe = this.route.params.pipe(
    map(({ id }) => id),
    filter(id => !!id), // <---- here
    switchMap((id: string) => 
     this.shippingService.getShippingById(id)))
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      this.shippingData = res;
      this.y= true;
    },
    err => this.error = err.error,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `tap` operator before your filter:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribe = this.route.params.pipe(
    map(({ id }) => id),
    tap((val) => { if (val === null) this.x = true }),
    filter(id => !!id),
    switchMap((id: string) => 
     this.shippingService.getShippingById(id)))
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      this.shippingData = res;
      this.y= true;
    },
    err => this.error = err.error,
  );
}
```

Comment: In this solution "if' underlined in red and there is information: '{' expected,
and the last ")" underlined in red and there is information: ';' expected. How to fix it?

Comment: you can do: `tap((val) => { if (val === null) this.x = true }),`, I've also edited the answer to be more precise